# ImportError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flash

In **clean.py** I have:

```
import datetime
import os

from flask_script import Manager
from sqlalchemy_utils import dependent_objects

from components import db, app
from modules.general.models import File
from modules.workflow import Workflow

manager = Manager(usage='Cleanup manager')

@manager.command
def run(dryrun=False):

    for abandoned_workflow in Workflow.query.filter(Workflow.current_endpoint ==                 "upload.upload_init"):
        if abandoned_workflow.started + datetime.timedelta(hours=12) < datetime.datetime.utcnow():
            print("Removing abandoned workflow {0} in project {1}".format(
                abandoned_workflow.id, abandoned_workflow.project.name
        ))

        if not dryrun:
            db.session.delete(abandoned_workflow)

    db.session.commit()


    for file in File.query.all():
        dependencies_number = dependent_objects(file).count()

        print("File {0} at {1} has {2} dependencies".format(file.name, file.path, dependencies_number))

        if not dependencies_number:
            file_delete(file, dryrun)

        if not dryrun:
            db.session.delete(file)

db.session.commit()

# List all files in FILE_STORAGE directory and delete ones tat don't have records in DB
all_files_hash = list(zip(*db.session.query(File.hash).all()))

for file in os.listdir(app.config['FILE_STORAGE']):
    if file.endswith('.dat'):
        continue

        if file not in all_files_hash:
            file_delete(os.path.join(app.config['FILE_STORAGE'], file), dryrun)enter code here
```

I need start **def run()**
in console I write:
    `python clean.py`
And I have outputs :

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "cleanup_command.py", line 7, in <module>
 from components import db, app
 ImportError: No module named 'components'
```

clean.py is located in- C:\App\model\clean.py

components.py is located in - C:\components.py

Workflow.py is located in - C:\modules\workflow\Workflow.py

Please, tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that modules for import are searched in certain locations: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path.

In your case you can put all source directory paths in `PYTHONPATH` var like:

```
PYTHONPATH=... python clean.py
```

But I guess it would be better to relocate your code files (i.e. put all the libs in one location)

Answer (score 0):

To start run() when you call `python clean.py`, Add these lines at the end of the script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = run()
    ## 0-127 is a safe return range, and 1 is a standard default error
    if r < 0 or r > 127: r = 1
    sys.exit(r)
```

Also as Eugene Primako mentioned it is better to relocate your code files in one location.

```
from components import db, app
ImportError: No module named 'components'
```

This means its looking for script named components.py in a location where clean.py is placed. This is the reason why you have got import error.